# MUMPS - Export to xml

Tags: xml, export, mumps

I need to export the data generated in the MUMPS system with a unique key for each appointment made. Data needs to be exported in XML, can I do that in MUMPS? Can anyone help me?
The data I need to export in XML format is
accession_number
Each exam has a unique identifier, if the patient performs more than one exam on the same day, each one will have a different Accession Number.

patient_id - Unique identifier of the exam

accession_number - Patient identifier

patient_name - Patient's name

patient_birthdate - Patient's date of birth
Example: YYYYMMDD

patient_sex - Patient's gender

patient_weight - Patient weight

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of application you use. Epic and VistA have their own XML export utilities.

I maintained some utilities here: https://github.com/shabiel/VISTA-xml-processing-utilities; but I would check with somebody in your EMR system on what's the proper API to use.

Comment: Hello, we use an application developed in the institution itself. It's not Epic and not Vista. It was developed in-house in MUMPS.

Comment: Okay. Try something like this: https://github.com/shabiel/M-Web-Server/blob/master/src/_webapi.m#L61. You will need to write it out to the file system or a socket using your M implementation's utilities. VistA has wrappers for these functions, but you don't use it.